# Do products like Ditra make tile removal more complicated?

Tags: tile, removal, remodeling, demolition

Products like [DITRA](http://www.schluter.com/6_1_ditra.aspx) are great to use when installing tile, but I can't help wondering what it'll be like to remove the tile later.  Is it more difficult to remove tile that's been laid on this type of product, or does it actually make tile removal easier?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tile is generally installed as a permanent fixture.  Removal is intended to be difficult - in fact easy removal is a clear indicator that the installation wasn't done well.  The sub-material is often destroyed in the removal process because of the force necessary for removal of the product.

DITRA, being textured, would hold onto the mortar used to mount the tile.  The only thing more complicated about demo where DITRA is involved is it's one more layer to be removed.

Comment: This is particularly evident watching Holmes on Homes, as basically all they do is fix improperly installed stuff. He's commented numerous times to the effect of "Boy, it's a good thing we didn't put this tile in, we'd be all day removing it" and they tear it out in half an hour. (Of course, then he also typically points out that if it was done right, they wouldn't have to remove it).